# change native thread priority on Android in c/c++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, pthreads

Insanely obscure pthread api for thread priority not only outlandishly incomprehensible, but also it just doesn't work on android.

So, is there a way for me to reduce or increase a thread's priority?

```
int currentPolicy;
struct sched_param sched;
status = pthread_getschedparam(pthread_self(), &currentPolicy, &sched);
printf("sched.sched_priority:%d currentPolicy:%d", sched.sched_priority, currentPolicy);
printf("priority min/max:%d/%d", sched_get_priority_min(currentPolicy), sched_get_priority_max(currentPolicy));
```

outputs:

> sched.sched_priority:0 currentPolicy:0
>
> priority min/max:0/0

Also, no matter what I do, pthread_setschedparam always return an error for me (Invalid argument).
In my code, I need to reduce priority of my handler thread to make sure that the other thread uses more cpu time. Or, alternatively, I could boost thread priority of my other thread that I want to use as more cpu compared to other threads in my process.

Is there any way for me to do that? I use native c++ code only.

**Edit:** From this post looks like android's threads are some kind of light weight processes and to modify priorities for them [setpriority](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority) should be used. It looks that the function works (getpriority before and after indicates that priority was modified). However, I don't see expected effect in my app.

Comment: "*... pthread_setschedparam always return an error for me (Invalid argument).*", so would you mind showing us what you did pass into the function to have it return `EINVAL`?

Comment: for currentPolicy I tried to pass all available values (0, 1, 2, 3). For sched.sched_priority I tried to set different value (-10, 10 etc). All fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's simple answer: use `int nice(int increment)`. It's declared in unistd.h

here's the code of the function from Android:

```
int nice(int increment)
{
    int  priority = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
    return setpriority( PRIO_PROCESS, 0, priority+increment);
}
```

so, `setpriority` can be used to set thread priority.

I actually got difference as expected in my code by using `nice(-10)` or `nice(10)`

Comment: where should I place this code ? is it for threads or the process ? also, what is the return value ? thanks

Comment: FWIW looks like this is declared in `<sys/resource.h>`

Comment: @nmr 5 years ago it might not have been the case

Comment: So, you mean, either `nice()` or `setpriority()` can be used? Also, is there any way for a user-level application to alter sched_priority other than SCHED_OTHER on a non-rooted Android device? I don't think so but just asking.

Comment: In your original question, about `setpriority()`, you said "However, I don't see expected effect in my app", and then you wrote your own answer like this.. With `setpriority()`, did you actually see any difference or not?

Comment: @Jenix I don't know what I meant 6 years ago :) Perhaps I didn't use `setpriority` correctly. My own answer shows what works on android.

Comment: This won't set the priority of the current thread, but the current process.

Comment: @ConstantinGeier The Linux implementation of `setpriority` differs from the POSIX standard, specifically `setpriority` sets the _thread_ priority, not the entire process priority. This is called out in the "Bugs" section of the Linux man pages: https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority
I've also verified this behavior by giving different threads different priorities via `setpriority` on Android and observing the results with `adb shell ps -T -p <pid> -l`

Answer (score 10):

Android threads are Linux threads.  Nothing special about them.

`setpriority()` alters the thread's "nice" value, which affects the priority at which the thread is scheduled.

`pthread_setschedparam()` can be used to change the *policy* as well.

Generally speaking, you can't raise the priority or change its policy without elevated privileges (`CAP_SYS_NICE`).  You can lower it, or raise it back to "normal" priority.

If you use `adb shell ps -t -p` you can see the priorities assigned to every thread.  This information is also included in Dalvik stack dumps.

Dalvik uses `setpriority()` to temporarily raise the GC thread's priority if necessary (to avoid priority inversion).  If you look at [this bit of code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/gingerbread/vm/alloc/Heap.c) around line 625 you can see it.  You can also see the call to `set_sched_policy()`, an Android library function that changes which [cgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) the thread is in.

Comment: That's close. `nice(int)` should be used on android which uses setpriority. Everything else just doesn't work. I also tried to search entire android source code and other functions aren't used.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set the priority of a POSIX thread in Android. The `nice()` and `setpriority()` functions configure the priority of a process, not of a single thread.

Comment: that incorrect, i have verified it myself. nice & set-priority(default) apply to current process which in android native world a linux LWP. your confusion may be stemming from fact that the priorities are inhereted by all launched threads. so if you set prio before launching child/worker threads the'll all have that prio.

Comment: Buy that does not mean you can change the policy/priority of a given thread after it is created/running.

Comment: I agree. There is no way to set the priority of ndk thread(s). Calling setpriority() with PRIO_PROCESS changes some priority (yet unknown to me which exactly) but In a simple test I created 2 std::thread and was calling setpriority() with different priorities in them - they alternating set the priority of themself and its coaleque.

Comment: The Linux implementation of `setpriority` differs from the POSIX standard; it changes the thread priority instead of the process priority. This difference is called out in the "Bugs" section of the Linux man pages: https://linux.die.net/man/2/setpriority I also tested this by creating multiple `std::thread`'s, using `pthread_gettid_np` to convert their `native_handle()` to a thread id, setting different priorities via `setpriority`, and verifying the results by looking at the NI and PRI columns of `adb shell ps -T -p <pid> -l`. My priority changes were applied per-thread, not process-wide