# Setting TThread priority on Android

Tags: android, delphi

I would like to change the priority of a real time audio thread on Android.
If I set `TThread.Priority` to any value except 0 I get an exception:

> EThread: Thread Error: Invalid argument"

How do I properly set the thread priority?

Comment: The documentation clearly explains the conditions under which you will get that error.

Comment: @BrodoFraggins: I see no such information in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Classes.TThread.Priority).

Answer (score 5):

On POSIX systems (like Android), there is a `TThread.Policy` property that specifies the thread's scheduling policy, which in turn controls how the `TThread.Priority` property behaves.  Most likely, the value you are trying to assign for the `Priority` does not make sense within the current `Policy`. For example, a `Policy` of `SCHED_OTHER` (the default) only supports a `Priority` of 0, whereas a `Policy` of `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR` support a `Priority` of 1-99 instead (some POSIX system may even limit them to 32).

So you have to make sure the `Policy` is set to the desired policy first, then you can change the `Priority` as needed.  Note, however, that some `Policy` values, such as `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR`, require root/admin rights in order to change their scheduling `Priority`.

None of this information is documented on the Embarcadero DocWiki, not even the existence of the `TThread.Policy` property.  I looked at the `TThread` source code and saw that it is using the POSIX `pthread_getschedparam()` and `pthread_setschedparam()` functions to get/set the thread's `Policy` and `Priority` values.  I then looked looked at online references for those functions, such as [this one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getschedparam.3.html).  So, in your case, `pthread_setschedparam()` is failing with this error:

```
EINVAL policy is not a recognized policy, or param does not make sense for the policy.
```

Comment: I have tried all available combinations of policy and different priority values. I found a different question which says setpriority should be used. Do you know how to call setpriority from Delphi? [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398075/change-native-thread-priority-on-android-in-c-c)